# Minimal color poster generation (Obama Hope style)

Tags: vector

I am trying to create images like this. How are these images created? I need the simplest way possible. Can it be done online somewhere?

[image]

Comment: you could try this tutorial. http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-inspirational-vector-political-poster--vector-17

Comment: Hi xkryptor, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My installation of Gimp comes with a filter for exactly this: *Filters → Artistic → Obama Hope.*

See also [here](http://registry.gimp.org/node/14291).

Comment: lolwut!? And it ain't even April 1st yet?

Comment: @Vincent: Is this really so surprising?

Comment: Why would one name this filter obama hope is the surprising thing. Its not like the effect hasnt been used way way longer than that.

Comment: @joojaa: Note that this filter reproduces the specific colours etc. of the Obama Hope poster, not only the thresholding (there is another filter for the well-known Che Guevara poster) – so the name does make some sense.

Comment: yes but still its not universal to understand what it means its too locale dependent of a name. There are 5.7 billion people who will have hard to relate to the name.

Comment: @joojaa: I don’t see your point. First of all, given the huge popularity and massive parodying and referencing of this poster, it is certainly well-known outside the US. Second, the name is not more or less specific than the style it’s describing. Third, I am pretty certain that more people can relate the style in question to *Obama* or *hope* than to any other description.

Comment: well known... well i asked about this amongst art students and one of 20 had seen one I asked engineering students and none had seen or heard of it. so hardly super universal.